# Change the app manifest parameters programmatically

Tags: c#, uwp, appxmanifest

I use FullTrustProcessLauncher to launch another app from my UWP application and I want to set the parameters of my manifest:

```
<desktop:ParameterGroup GroupId="OtherGroup" Parameters=aVariable/>
```

Is there a way to change the app manifest programmatically of an UWP app?

Comment: This sounds like all you want to do is pass information to the application you are launching. To accomplish that, you don't have to fiddle with the manifest.

Comment: Exactly, How can I do that ?

Comment: By asking **that** question (instead of your proposed solution).

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, [there is no such way](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/schemas/appxpackage/appx-package-manifest):

> The package manifest is an XML document that contains the info the system needs to deploy, display, or update a Windows app. This info includes package identity, package dependencies, required capabilities, visual elements, and extensibility points.

That means that manifest is used to deploy app and set its permissions to the system. So it cannot change values in runtime. That's why such ability isn't implemented.